# how to get object's some properties async in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

I have Array of Json object which I was fetching from server by Http call let suppose the array is

```
var someArray=[
{id:1,name:'someName',status:'no-data'},
{id:1,name:'someName',status:'no-data'},
{id:1,name:'someName',status:'no-data'}]
```

And I have rendered the data into table in angular using ngFor

```
  <tr *ngFor="let it of someArray">
  <td>{{it.id}}</td>
  <td>{{it.name}}</td>
  <td>{{it.status}}</td>
  </tr>
```

I want to know how can I fetch `status` attribute of `someArray` async (currently I has `no-data` but It has values let say 'live'  ) so that in first API call it should fetch someArray render it on table and then it fetch the status of each object of array async wise.

Kindly refer me some docs or help will be appreciated :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you should perform this by your back end to get an object with status and rendered data. but if you want to make it with Angular you should do  a `map` on your `someArray` and call your back end

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi I have studies this kind of thing in BackboneJs where there is  collection and models , can you share some docs ?

Comment: If you're using a MongoDB with mongoose think to use populate() method https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html. if not try to make JOINs Query to get all data with wanted children

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking here, but there is an async pipe you can use on the for loop

```html
<tr *ngFor="let it of someArray | async">
  <td>{{it.id}}</td>
  <td>{{it.name}}</td>
  <td>{{it.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I mean I want to make separate  API call to get `status` attribute after its other attributes already rendered on table . It should show loading for status and then show real value after API call . @Chris , You got my point ?

Comment: sorry, no - I'm not understanding what you are asking. You just want to show a loading status while loading the data?

Comment: status has value `no-data` here , I want to get its value (which is `status:live` on db) from backend after nested API call on run time . @Chris

Comment: how to do that nested ajax call ?

Comment: you have only shown us a plain array with 4 items and a small bit of HTML with a loop.  we have no idea what the code looks like for your ajax calls